# Generate password with minimum and maximum length : batch file

Tags: batch-file

Trying to generate password with given characters but need to define minimum and maximum password string length inside batch file.

i created batch file which is generating password string perfectly but i was unable to define length of string in Min_RNDLength & Max_RNDLength field.

```
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Min_RNDLength=8
Set Max_RNDLength=30
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
Echo Random string is !_RndAlphaNum!
```

not sure how to overcome this issue.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: That's simple math `set /A "RNDLength=%Random% %% (Max_RNDLength-Min_RNDLength) +Min_RNDLength"`

Comment: i tried just now but not sure where to fit that code , still not working , can you elaborate further by answering

Comment: @aschipfl this min and max length code is not working

Comment: In your 2nd last line, currently the var `%_RNDLength%` is ***not*** defined and resolves to nothing causing an error interpreting `_loop` as a command. Insert `set /A "_RNDLength=%Random% %% (Max_RNDLength-Min_RNDLength) +Min_RNDLength"` just beneath `set Max_RNDLength=30`

Comment: Well, "it doesn't work" is not a precise error description, so please be specific! And don't comment, [edit] your question accordingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /A Min_RNDLength=8, Max_RNDLength=30
Set Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

rem Randomize internal random number (optional)
rem for /L %%i in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set /A !random!

rem Get random lenght between limits:
set /A RNDLength=%Random% %% (Max_RNDLength-Min_RNDLength) + Min_RNDLength

Set "RndAlphaNum="
rem Generate such a number of random characters from Alphanumeric set (62 characters)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%RNDLength%) do (
   set /A RND=!random! %% 62
   for %%r in (!RND!) do set "RndAlphaNum=!RndAlphaNum!!Alphanumeric:~%%r,1!"
)

Echo Random string is %RndAlphaNum%
```

Comment: this worked perfect